# Visual studio preinstalled localdb instances can be deleted?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio and SQL Server to start learning some things, when I open VS I see these two instances marked in red that I did not create:

[image: Visual Studio SQL Server Object Explorer]

I tried:

- Delete them using `sqllocaldb` commands in CMD.
- Delete the registries in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances`
- Delete the folders in `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances`

But every time I opened Visual Studio, these instances were recreated.